# How to validate field that's not bind to any element

Tags: angularjs

I have one field that's not bind to any form element, but I would like to add required validation to it like I have for any other fields that are bind to some controls. I tried to use

```
<input type="hidden" name="requiredField" ng-model="vm.requiredField" required />
```

but while field was marked as `$invalid` and the whole form was still `$valid`.

Do you have any idea how to make such validation?

Comment: Is the field inside the form?

Comment: Yes, it is in the form

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it looks like it should works. The reason why it doesn't work for me is because there was hidden code that changed `$invalid` field manually. I found it by using such script: https://github.com/paulirish/break-on-access